# Git clone to multiple repos(more than 70) one by one through jenkins file fail

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

Using git through Jenkins pipeline. Sometimes the same code works, so no issue with authentication.
What happens is it clone some repo and fail for some and this is also not the same like at times work for 10 repo and sometimes fail after just cloning two repos

This is the error we get :

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@gitlab.com:equipay_htdocs/portal/wp-content/plugins/cronjob-scheduler.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:998)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1239)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1299)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress -- git@gitlab.com:equipay_htdocs/portal/wp-content/plugins/cronjob-scheduler.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a host where the memory is very fragmented, and can't allocate a page a contiguous memory to fork the process for hosting an SSH session.

If memory fragmenting is the apparent cause, the solution is to access the server via other means and to restart some of the services, which are always running. I have found Apache and MySQL to be a culprit on VM's since VM's don't have a swap partition. If this does not work, then to reboot the host.

The next suggestion could be, if you have more number of incoming requests than allowed.

If the number of unauthenticated connections goes over the sshd:MaxStartUps parameter, sshd starts rejecting those connections.

The MaxStartups in sshd_config could be increased, but to see the number of incoming connections is over the limit, before increasing the MaxStartUps.

Comment: It is working, I don't have to do anything. What happens is it will work after some time on its own. But fails in one run for all repositories.